# Find the associations for an ActiveRecord class at run-time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I would like to find the assocations of an ActiveRecord class at runtime...

Let's assume I have the following:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chairs
  has_many :pens
end

class Chair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

How can I find out at runtime that Person "has many" Chairs and Pens, and vice versa?  I'm looking for a method that would return an array of strings (if such a method exists).  i.e.

```
Person.has_many_assocations
```

would return:

```
["chairs", "pens"]
```

and

```
Pen.belongs_to_associations
```

would return:

```
["person"]
```

Am I missing a method like this that exists??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the [ActiveRecord::Reflection](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html) class may be what you're looking for. From the documentation:

```
  Account.reflect_on_all_associations             # returns an array of all associations
  Account.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)  # returns an array of all has_many associations
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty silly thing to do run-time. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I assume that there are a simple and more commonly used solution to whatever your problem is.

If I had to, I'd use `TheModel.read_inheritable_attribute(:reflections)`.

Comment: Uhhh... think Rake task. One that needs to know the associations.

Comment: The models themselves knows about the associations. So I'm still not following you ; )