# Rails ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have an User model.

How I can get all associations between the User model with other models ?

I need to know the model names and the association type (1..1, 1..m, m..m ...)

I don't want to use the db/schema.rb file

Comment: Many, many duplicates:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178587/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644718/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880591/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259529/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reflect_on_all_associations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_all_associations) class method on the `User` model.

This will return an array of reflection objects. On those objects you can call `macro` method to find out the association type (`:has_many`, `:belongs_to`, etc.), and `klass` method to know the, em, class of the associated object(s).